# Python:Getting argument of type int not iterable error

Tags: python

why am I getting a "argument of type int not iterable error"? Here is my simple code.

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    out = x[0]
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        if x[i] in out:
            print "duplicate " + str(x[i])
        else:
            out.append(x[i])    
    return out

remove_duplicates([4,5,5,4])
```

Got the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in remove_duplicates
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign:

```
out = x[0]
```

`out` is now an `int`, you cannot do things like `x[i] in out`,  or `out.append(x[i])` since `out` is an integer.

You want:

```
out = [x[0]]
```

if you want `out` to be a list.

Answer (score 2):

`out = x[0]` should be `out = [x[0]]`.

The error you received indicates that the check `x[i] in out` was an attempt to look for something within `out`, and since `out` was an `int`, this failed since you can't have something inside an `int`. Instead, you should make `out` a *list* containing only `x[0]` initially.

Answer (score 2):

`if x[i] in out:` requires `out` to be an iterable i.e. a list, dict, set, etc. However, you have initialised `out` as a single element (`x[0]`), not a collection.
If you intended `out` to be a list initialised with the first element of `x`, do this instead:

```
out = [x[0]]
```