# Iterate int variable to do in operator check

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I already referred the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579095/argument-of-type-int-is-not-iterable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851723/pythongetting-argument-of-type-int-not-iterable-error). Please don't mark as duplicate. My python version is 3.8.8

I have a dataframe like as below

```
customer_id   r  f  m  h  y  
   1          4  3  3  3  3    
   2          5  4  2  1  4
   3          3  1  1  1  1
   4          2  2  2  2  2
```

Based on the code snippet found in this repository [here](https://pypi.org/project/rfm/), am trying to do the below

a) Assign a `segment_label` to each customer based on their `r, f, m, h , y` values

So, I was working on the below code. But the problem is am getting an error in the 1st if-clause. I already tried replacing `in` keyword with `==` symbol. But it doesn't do the check and ends up in else clause for all records/customers

```
classes = []
classes_append = classes.append
cust = 'unique_key'
for row in df.iterrows():
    rec = row[1]
    print(rec)
    r = rec['r']
    f = rec['f']
    y = rec['y']
    p = rec['h']
    if (r in (4)) and (f in (4)) and (y in (2,3)) and (h in (3)): # I replaced `in` keyword with `==` symbol as well. The code works but it doesn't check the condition. So, ends up in else clause.
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Champions'})
    elif (r in (4)) and (f in (4)) and (y in (1,)) and (h in (2,3)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Short Tenure - Promising'})
    elif (r in (3,4)) and (f in (3,4)) and (y in (3,)) and (h in (1,2,3)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Loyal Customers'})
    elif (r in (3,4,5)) and (f in (3,4,5)) and (y in (2,)) and (h in (1,2)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Potential Loyalist'})
    elif (r in (3,4)) and (f in (3,4)) and (y in (1,)) and (h in (1)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Short Tenure - Average'})
    elif (r in (2,)) and (f in (1,2,3)) and (y in (1,2,3)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Needs Attention'})
    elif (r in (4)) and (f in (1,2)) and (y in (1,2,3)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:'Occasional and New Customers'})
    elif (r in (1,)) and (y in (1,2,3)):
        classes_append({rec[cust]:"Lost"})
    else:
        print("hi")
        classes.append({0:[row[1]['r'],row[1]['f'],row[1]['m']]})
    accs = [list(i.keys())[0] for i in classes]
    segments = [list(i.values())[0] for i in classes]
    df['segment_label'] = df[cust].map(dict(zip(accs,segments)))
```

The error is

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `in`? For equality? If yes then use ==

Comment: equality doesn't check the value. It all ends up in else clause. But this code used to work earlier. Only change, I downgraded my python version to 3.8.8 and now it is not working

Comment: Thats not how equality works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `(4)` does not define a tuple with single item apparently hence you get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. That's why it stops at the line

```
if (r in (4)) and (f in (4)) and (y in (2,3)) and (h in (3)):
```

Maybe try replacing tuples with lists as follows (e.g. here list of one item):

```
>>> r = 5
>>> r in [4]
False
```

so your first `if` statement will become

```
if (r in [4]) and (f in [4]) and (y in [2,3]) and (h in [3]):
```

**Update**: as The Great suggested in comments adding `comma` to single item tuple solved the problem. Perhaps that should be the correct answer.

Comment: I see. just adding `comma` to single item tuples, solved the problem.

Comment: Wonderful! Good to know it does ;)